# A good text editor for learning the implementation?

Tags: linux, text-editor

I would like to learn how an *extensible* text editor is implemented. By extensible, I mean the ability to augment the functionality of the main program with code written by the users like plugins, runtime configuration files etc.

Which one would you recommend - `vim`, `emacs` or something else? There is [kilo](https://www.finseth.com/craft/) which is pretty popular for its DIY approach and I am considering that as a starting point, but my main focus is on learning how to write a software that is extendable.

I like a few things about `emacs` like the readability of the configuration file (just invoking plain old functions with arguments), mutating the environment itself etc. There are also some good books on `emacs` like [The Craft of Text Editing](https://www.finseth.com/craft/). One drawback, however, is that `elisp` can be slow at times.

I like a few things about `vim` like the modal editing (`<action>` `<motion>`), the speed of editing etc. However, the configuration file is a bit cryptic at times because it is mostly about rebinding one set of keys to another, which I don't find really readable or intuitive (internally it could be invoking functions too but the readability is less). Also, I am not sure if there are any textbooks on `vim`'s design?

Here is a very nice resource I found on the Internet about Text Editors: http://texteditors.org/.

Answer (score 4):

See at [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor, it is written in Lazarus, and has all possible extensions: python plugins, color themes, syntax lexers, etc.

List: http://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Add-on_types

Answer (score 3):

I would think there are several approaches to making something extensible.

Look at Atom, developed by Github. (atom.io)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking extensible is a general term too. But I think a hands-on experience would be nice.